# Absolute position div flows outisde relative position div when console window is opened

Tags: css, absolute

I created a main div `signup-background` and a div inside it `signup-form`. On opening the console, the form flows outside the background.

```scss
#signup-backgroud {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#signup-form {
    background-color: white;
    width: 500px;
    height: 550px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 30%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

[image: Image attached]

I understand the problem is because I gave the top and left for the `signup-form`. But I can't resolve it.

Comment: As I can see, you want to make your background full-scree. Can you try to set the height of the background to `100vh` instead of `100%`

Comment: No the problem is since the form is included inside the main div, on opening the console, the inside div is coming out from the main div. Your solution is not working.

Comment: Don't use `position: absolute` if you don't want elements to break the flow. What should the final layout look like? How should it behave on smaller screens?

Comment: I just need a scroll bar to appear , the rest should remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a scrollbar, you could try to apply a `overflow:scroll` on #signup-backgroud.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not post a complete example of the problem, I will not post a complete example of the solution. I'll just tell you what to do, since there is no way to know your HTML markup, this may not work.

Remove the position:absolute, this removes your element from the document flow and your request is to have the document flow with it... Either use relative positionning or margins to accomplish your positioning.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an `absolute` position for the div with id `signup-form`, an `absolute` `div` is a related `div` to its `relative` parent, so better use percentage for the dimensions, not fixed values.

This is my example based on your `CSS` classes and `divs` in your image:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#signup-backgroud {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5%;
}

#signup-form {
    background-color: white;
    width: 90%;
    max-height: 80%;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 1em 0;
}

.example-input {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: auto;
}

.example-button {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="signup-backgroud">
  <div id="signup-form">
    <input class="example-input" type="text" />
    <input class="example-input" type="text" />
    <input class="example-input" type="text" />
    <input class="example-input" type="text" />
    <input class="example-input" type="text" />
    <button class="example-button">Register</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou forthe solution. It partly solved the problem